# Python OpenCV cannot display image correctly after transformation

Tags: python, image, opencv, compression, pca

Today I was trying to compress the image below, using sklearn's PCA algorithm in Python.

[image: Baby Yoda Image that was tried to be compressed]

Because the image is RGB (3 channels), I first reshaped the image, so that it becomes 2D. Then, I applied  the PCA algorithm on the data to compress the image. After the image was compressed, I inversed the PCA transformation and reshaped the approximated (decompressed) image back to its original shape.

However, when I tried to display the approximated image I got this weird result here:

[image]

While the **image is stored correctly** with the `cv2.imwrite` function, OpenCV **fails to display the image** correctly using `cv2.imshow`. Do You have any idea why this might be happening?

My code is below:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import cv2
import numpy as np

image_filepath = 'baby_yoda_image.jpg'

# Loading image from disk.
input_image = cv2.imread(image_filepath)
height = input_image.shape[0]
width = input_image.shape[1]
channels = input_image.shape[2]

# Reshaping image to perform PCA.
print('Input image shape:', input_image.shape)
#--- OUT: (533, 800, 3)

reshaped_image = np.reshape(input_image, (height, width*channels))
print('Reshaped Image:', reshaped_image.shape)
#--- OUT: (533, 2400)

# Applying PCA transformation to image. No whitening is applied to prevent further data loss.
n_components = 64
whitening = False
pca = PCA(n_components, whitening)
compressed_image = pca.fit_transform(reshaped_image)

print('PCA Compressed Image Shape:', compressed_image.shape)
#--- OUT: (533, 64)
print('Compression achieved:', np.around(np.sum(pca.explained_variance_ratio_), 2)*100, '%')
#--- OUT: 97.0 %    

# Plotting images.
approximated_image = pca.inverse_transform(compressed_image)
approximated_original_shape_image = np.reshape(approximated_image, (height, width, channels))

cv2.imshow('Input Image', input_image)
cv2.imshow('Compressed Image', approximated_original_shape_image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you have clipped the data to range 0 to 255 and formatted it to 8-bits (uint8).

Comment: indeed, this seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution to this problem, thanks to @fmw42 . After the transformation, there were **negative values** in the pixels **and** also **values that exceeded 255**.

Luckily, OpenCV does take care of this problem with this line of code:

```
approximated_uint8_image = cv2.convertScaleAbs(approximated_original_shape_image)
```